# PHPUnit in fresh Symfony 3 installation

Tags: phpunit, symfony

I installed Symfony 3 with the command line as they show in their documentation, and installed PHPUnit.

```
phpunit --version
PHPUnit 6.0.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

When I run phpunit in the command line, I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in D:\symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase.php on line 23
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue related to PHPUnit 6 and a known 'bug' or incompatibility with Symfony (the background is that PHPUnit 6 expects and only supports PHP7 while Symfony 3 still supports lower PHP versions).

I suggest to use PHPUnit 5.7 as a workaround for now.

See this issue description/discussion on [Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21534)

Comment: Thanks @LBA for your answer, I'm using PHP7 in my server, and from [here](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-achieves-100-php7-compatibility) you can see that Symfony 3 is 100% compatible with PHP7

Comment: I just read it, and in the same time tried it with PHPUnit 5.6 and it's working, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can change PHPUnit to 5.7 version, as LBA suggest but this is not solution.

This error message simply tells you that you should replace:

`use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;`

with

`use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`

works for me!